# Invalid Output for Coursera Python Assignment

Tags: python

I'm doing the Coursera Python for Everybody stream and I'm stuck on Assignment 10.2. I'm getting invalid output for it. Here is what the assignment asks:

> Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the
>   distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can pull
>   the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then
>   splitting the string a second time using a colon.
>
> ```
> From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
> ```
>
> Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the
>   counts, sorted by hour as shown below.

Here is my code:

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()
lst = list()

for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue
    words = line.split()
    words = words[5]
    words = words.split(":")
    for word in counts:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

lst = list()
for key, val in counts.items():
    lst.append((key, val))

lst.sort()

print lst
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong. Any advice or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the inputs and expected outputs? Edited to see the sample input better

Comment: Looks like your inner iterator is wrong `word in counts`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are iterating through the wrong thing in the inner loop: it should be `for word in words`, not `for word in counts`.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"

handle = open(name)

hours = dict()

for line in handle:
   if line.startswith("From "):

    hour = line.split()[5].split(':')[0] 

    hours[hour] = hours.get(hour, 0) + 1

for key, value in sorted(hours.items(), None):
    print key, value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)


counts = {}

for line in handle:
   if not line.startswith("From "):continue

   time = line.split()
   time = time[5]
   hour = time.split(':')
   hour = hour[0] 

   counts[hour] = counts.get(hour, 0) + 1


for k, v in sorted(counts.items()):

    print (k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = dict()
for line in handle:
if line.startswith ('From '):
    words = line.split()
    hour=words[5].split(':')
    counts[hour[0]]= counts.get(hour[0],0)+1
lst=list()
for key, val in counts.items():
    lst.append((key,val))
lst=sorted(lst)
for a,b in lst:
    print (a,b)
```

Comment: Great first answer :) but it would help to point out what you're changing here for the asker.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question with just code, try to explain it, maximum when there are some other answers, so you should show the Pros of yours

Answer (score 0):

```
name =input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1: 
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    if line.startswith("From "):
        time = line.split()[5].split(":")
        counts [time[0]] = counts.get(time[0], 0) + 1

#print sorted( [ (v,k) for k,v in counts.items()] )

list = list()

for key, value in counts.items():
    list.append( (key,value) )
list.sort()

for hour, counts in list:
    print (hour, counts)
```

Comment: Consider adding explanation to this question. Why does this work, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('words.txt')
dic = dict()
lst = list()


for line in file :
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue

    words = line.split()
    words= words[5].split(':')

    words = words[0]


    dic[words] = dic.get(words,0)+1

for k,v in dic.items():
    lst.append((k,v))
lst.sort()
for k,v in lst:
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: it would help to explain your solution

Comment: While this might answer the question, your should [edit] your answer to provide an explanation of *how* this answers the question, which helps provide context for future readers. A code block by itself is not immediately useful for those who might come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
g={}
for line in handle :
    if not line.startswith('From'): continue
    werds=line.split()[5:6]
    for werd in werds :
      we=werd.split(':')[0]
      g[we]=g.get(we,0)+1
lst=list()
for v,k in g.items() :
    new=(v,k)
    lst.append(new)
lst=sorted(lst)
for v,k in lst :
    print(v,k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
one = dict()
for line1 in handle:
    if line1.startswith("From "):
        lst1 = line1.split()
        lst2 = lst1[5].split(":")
        word = lst2[0]
        one[word] = one.get(word,0) + 1
lst3 = list()
for k,v in one.items():
    tup = (k,v)
    lst3.append(tup)
lst3 = sorted(lst3,)
for k,v in lst3:
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: Please **edit** your answer to provide an explanation. This is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow. But it's _especially_ useful here, where there are **eight** existing answers. What sets your answer apart? Under what circumstances would your answer be preferred over the existing approaches? Remember, each new answer adds another post people with this problem need to evaluate. Make it easier for them to understand the differences, and why they should consider your code over others.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
h = dict()
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        l = line.split()[5].split(':')[0]
        h[l] = h.get(l, 0) +1
  
for k,v in sorted(h.items(), None):
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: A quick prose explanation of why this code works while the questioners doesn't (possibly with links to docs) will strengthen this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

#### Opening the file

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

lst = list()
counts = dict()
```

#### Splitting each line of the file to get words, then word at 6th place, then in that first letter of that 6th word splitted by ':', appending that into the list

```
for lines in handle:
    if not lines.startswith('From '): continue
    words = lines.split()
    words = words[5]
    words = words.split(':')
    lst.append(words[0])
```

#### Now counting the letters occurred at different no. of times

```
for i in lst:
    counts[i] = counts.get(i,0) + 1
```

#### Finally sorting them by key(here time)

```
for k, v in sorted(counts.items()):
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter file: ")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"

handle = open(name)
hours = dict()

for line in handle:
    # Skipping lines we don't need
    if not line.startswith("From "): 
        continue
    words = line.split()
    # Finding text in the line that we need
    time = words[5]                  
    time = time.split(":")
    hour_time = time[0]
    # Adding to the dictionary and checking if it already there
    hours[hour_time] = hours.get(hour_time, 0) + 1 

#Sorting dictionary using sorted() method
hours_sorted = sorted(hours.items())
for key, value in sorted(hours.items()):
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! The question asks for explaination, advise or tips. You can add code to you answer, but posting only code does not make it an answer. Please give some exolaination too.

Comment: First we are looking for the lines we need. Then find the specific position of hours on the line. Then we add this information to the dictionary. Finally we sort the dictionary the way we need.

Comment: I get what your code is doing, but some people won't understand the code by themselves. So, answers should contain some directions and/or details. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to understand writing good answers. All the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
count=dict()

#Loop and extract hour 
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith("From") and not line.startswith("From:"):
        line=line.split()
        hrs=line[5]
        hrs=hrs.split(":")
        hrs=hrs[0]
        count[hrs]=count.get(hrs,0)+1

sorted_count=dict(sorted(count.items())) 

for key,value in sorted_count.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"

handle = open(name)
hours = dict()

for line in handle:
    if line.startswith("From "):
        hour = line.split()[5].split(':')[0] 
        hours[hour] = hours.get(hour, 0) + 1

for key, value in sorted(hours.items(), None):
    print key, value
```